# Theta Runtime of a triple loop that essentially much less than n^3

Tags: algorithm, loops, runtime, analysis, big-o

I was looking at a programming question today and I had an issues finding the theta runtime of it. Basically, within my question, I form the following loop structure:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        for(int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
            //check some condition
```

By obvious inspection, it is O(n^3). More accurately, it is o(n^3). However, I want to know what the theta runtime of this is. If you examine this loop, the actual amount of times the inner condition executes is n!/3!(n-3)! since it is evaluating all combinations of n numbers without repetition.

Is there a way to express the theta runtime in polynomial form other than n choose r?

For example, the runtime of selection sort (similar but with only 2 for loops) can be evaluated by looking at the number of instructions being executed. n + (n-1) + (n-2) ... + 1 would simplify to n(n+1) / 2.

Comment: `More accurately, it is o(n^3)`: No, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n!/3!(n-3)! = n(n-1)(n-2)/3! = (n^2-n)(n-2)/6 = (n^3-2n^2-n^2+2n)/6 
            = (n^3 -3n^2 + 2n)/6
```

You can show easily<sup>1</sup> that for large enough values of `n`:

```
1/2 n^3 < (n^3 -3n^2 + 2n)/6 < 2n^3
```

So when it comes to asymptotic notation, it is in `Theta(n^3)`, and NOT in `o(n^3)`.

---

(1) One way to show it is:

```
lim 1/2n^3 /  ((n^3 -3n^2 + 2n)/6)  when n->infinity = 1/2 < infinity
```

And similarly for the other inequality